# Parameter index out of range when filtering mysql data to show in a JTable

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Good Day

I am trying to retrieve data from a database into jTable. When the user writes in the textfield the required data it displays it in the table.

What I get is

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
```

Here is my codes

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hr","root","MZaa8891@");
    String Sql="Select recName,phoneNo,quali,major,Uni,status,IntDate,interviewer  from rect "; 
    ps= con.prepareStatement(Sql);
    ps.setString(1, jTextField1.getText());
    rs =ps.executeQuery();
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
    model.setRowCount(0);

    while(rs.next()){
        Object obj [] = {
            rs.getString("recName"),
            rs.getString("phoneNo"),
            rs.getString("quali"),
            rs.getString("major"),
            rs.getString("Uni"),
            rs.getString("status"),
            rs.getDate("IntDate"),
            rs.getString("interviewer")
        };
            model.addRow(obj);
    }        
} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: `String Sql="Select recName,phoneNo,quali,major,Uni,status,IntDate,interviewer  from rect "` there are no parameters to bind to - you actually need to provide a filter/where clause, maybe `String Sql="Select recName,phoneNo,quali,major,Uni,status,IntDate,interviewer  from rect where rename = ?"` as an example

Answer (score 1):

You have missed some parameter in the where clause:

> Query: Select
>   recName,phoneNo,quali,major,Uni,status,IntDate,interviewer  from rect
>   where something = ?

```
String Sql="Select recName,phoneNo,quali,major,Uni,status,IntDate,interviewer  from rect where something = ?"; 
ps= con.prepareStatement(Sql);
ps.setString(1, jTextField1.getText());
rs =ps.executeQuery();
```

Comment: I did the condition with  where concat('recName','phoneNo','quali','major','Uni','status','IntDate','interviewer') and I am getting the same error

Comment: You got to make it  `where concat('recName','phoneNo','quali','major','Uni','status','IntDate','interviewer')  = ?` then it should work

Comment: However the correctness of the retrieval operation is determined by the actual value of `jTextField1.getText()`

Comment: Now I am not getting  the error but when I add the correct actual value it wont dispaly for me anything

Comment: Try to debug it, I would suggest you print the value in `jTextField1.getText()` and explicitly test the query in SQL developer or some other tool